# How to see when the washing with Bosch dishwasher is over?

Tags: smart-home

I have SMV25CX03R Bosch dishwasher. It is not easy to control when the washing is over.  This is built-in machine, so all LEDs and buttons are hidden when the door is closed. I am thinking about a way to be able to see it remotely.

The following solutions I see:

1. Use a smart socket to control power consumption. If it is close to 0, most probably the washing is finished. Will that work?
2. There are similar dishwaters SMV2IKX1HR, SMV2IMX1GR, SMV2HMX3FR with wifi (Home Connect) built-in. It is quite possible that the Wi-Fi module is already installed on my device, but it is just disabled. Is there any way to check it? Tried to find a service manual for similar machines, but it looks like it is not available.
3. Or the Wi-Fi module is a simple esp8266 module, which I can add myself. But I have no idea how to check it.

What can be done here?

Comment: start by determining if something specific happens when the wash cycle is complete

Comment: this is a question and answer site ... it is not a discussion forum ... please ask one focused, answerable question

Answer (score 2):

There are no deactivated modules in Bosch dishwashers and the Wi-Fi module that is used is proprietary. You can order it in the [Bosch shop](https://www.bosch-home.com/de/shop/10014473) but your dishwasher will likely not work with it.
Dishwashers that do have Home Connect usually have it directly next to the power module ([third exploded view parts 660 & 662](https://www.bosch-home.co.uk/supportdetail/product/SMI88TS46E/29#/Tabs=section-spareparts/)). So if you really want to double check you can. Or you can trust the documentation that it's not there [in your model](https://www.bosch-home.co.uk/supportdetail/product/SMV25CX03R/01#/Tabs=section-spareparts/) (third view again).

Solution one is something I'm not sure about. Generally dishwashers run in program cycles with different phases. There might be phases were the dishwasher is basically just running down a timer before starting the next phase and that might be so close in power to being finished and not doing anything anymore. At least close enough for your socket to get problems distinguishing it.

So I guess you'll have to track a few runs to build a profile of the programs you're running and see if it's precise enough.

Comment: Might be easier to just time how long it takes and trigger this based on the first increase in power usage.

Comment: @hardillb that would work only if you always use the same program, though. Also I know some washing machines adapt program length to the amount of clothes or something like that, not sure if there aren't dishwashers doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

I went with your option #1 for my washing machine. I've got Zooz Z-Wave ZEN15 plug hooked up with SmartThings. It measures when the power consumption goes above 5W and monitors when it's <1W for a period of time. If <1W longer than 2 minutes - sends me a notification that wash cycle is done.

Why do you need to wait before checking? Because wash machine rotates clockwise, then stops, then rotates CCW, so you do not want to report end of wash while it waits between changing direction.

Comment: I don't think that a dishwasher alternates directions

Comment: Dishwashers don't rotate at 1600rpm so the motor is not as much of a dominating factor as it is in a washing machine energy-wise and it might be able depending on the model to reverse direction quite fast.

Comment: It's all related to power consumption regardless of what mechanism inside is consuming it: motor, water pump, heater, logic board, etc...